# backup my debian server to mycloud ex2 every hour

Tags: linux, debian, backup, mysql

I have a Debian web server with MySQL and I have a 'My Cloud EX2 Ultra'.

How can I backup my Debian server to 'My Cloud EX2 Ultra' every hour ?

'My Cloud EX2 Ultra' is a network hard drive .
 connected to the internet

and Debian web server is connected to internet via different network

### i want to backup my www/html directory to the 'My Cloud EX2 Ultra'

i have succeeded connecting from 'My Cloud EX2 Ultra' to the Debian web server via ssh

Comment: This is very likely to get closed as too broad.  You either need to provide more info and be more specific, or show us what you've tried so far.  For example, what is the My Cloud EX2 Ultra, is a physical device connected to the server, or is it a cloud storage service accessed over the network, etc.  Don't expect us to go googling to find that out - add it to the question (by editing the question and improving it).

Comment: i have edit the question

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways of achieving what you want.

One possible method would be to use `rsync` to backup over the SSH connection you've already established. The basics of using rsync for backup are covered in the Ubuntu documentation page, here: [rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync).

To run the backup every hour you can create a `crontab` entry as detailed here: [CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

If you need an incremental backup then you might also want to explore using the `--link-dest=DIR` option with rsync to point to the location of the previous backup directory and back-up each hour to a new directory. More details can be found in the `rsync` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).